# backface visibility Making text blurry in child element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make stack-able hexagons for my layout, made using css3's wonderful transform capabilities! The only problem is that when I and a :hover effect to change opacity on it, during the transition it changes the anti-alias properties, smooths all lines, and makes the text blurry. It also temporarily dis-aligns everything around it, though it all settles back after a second or so. While this doesn't necessarily conflict with the functionality of the site, it's rather sloppy looking.

I tried to resolve the issue by changing the code to this:

http://jsfiddle.net/QPbJL/

While this fixes the bugginess of it all, now my text is blurry, during transition and otherwise. I've tried adding -webkit-backspace-visibility: none; to the .HexDesc, since that's the direct container for the text.

```
.HexIn2 {
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;

-webkit-background-size: 125%;
-moz-background-size: 125%;
background-size: 125%;
visibility: visible;

-webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-60deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-60deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-60deg);
transform: rotate(-60deg);
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

    .HexDesc {
    padding: 3px; 0px 3px 0px;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:none !important;
    background: #ffffff;
    color:#000;
    margin-top:106px;
    height: 81px;
    font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
    line-height:85%;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    font-size: 13px;
    }
```

However, this has had zero effect. I've also tried throwing "!important" in there, to try and make it over-ride everything else in that div, and zilch again! It's like anything in the HexDesc container as far as backface-visibility has absolutely zero effect! This is very frustrating :C I was wondering if anyone knew why this was happening, and any way I could get around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is often the case with "middle" values. For rotation, you'll get the blur off only at 0, 90, 180, 270, 360... This is a bug from the browsers themselves.
You might notice that this applies to many things in css (for example, opacity often has trickle down effect when not at 1 or 0).

In your case, in your jsfiddle, if you replace all `120deg` with `180deg` and all `60deg` with `90deg`, it'll work perfectly. (meaning no blur, but you don't get the hexagon anymore). For the triangles, i'd recommend making them with this border hack (http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/). You can get to an identical result.

For the "temporarily dis-align", it is also a known bug from Chrome (and possibly other browsers, I don't know). Even if you go to gmail or youtube, you'll still see that happening.

Comment: So there's no way to resolve this without removing my hex code as it is currently? :c bummeeeeeeer. But, it's a newer thing, isn't it. I should expect bugs like this ^^; doesn't mean I won't fervently hope for a better day! I'll just switch things over to a border-based hexagon style. Thanks for the support Florian, I appreciate it!

Comment: And yes, all prefixed (-webkit-, -moz-...) values are still in the experimental state, so you can expect kinks.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to do it. I clicked the green check mark for the sake of experimentation in the hopes that that was it? Lol, let me know if there's something else I should do to validate it.

Comment: That is indeed how you do it. Thanks :)

Comment: Same solution works for translateX or TanslateY. Thanks Sheraff. (EX: instead translateX(-50%) i used translateX(-51%).