# Blurry text on transform:rotate and backface-visibility:hidden in Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, rotation, overflow

I'm getting blurry text on transform:rotate and backface-visibility:hidden in Chrome.

For sharp edges in a rotated element I use `backface-visibility:hidden`. Without `backface-visibility` the edges of each div are blurred. But with `backface-visibility:hidden` all the items in this div are blurred.

Here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/D69d4/10/

Where's the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [backface visibility Making text blurry in child element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771677/backface-visibility-making-text-blurry-in-child-element)